# Time complexity in nested loops and streams

Tags: java, java-stream, time-complexity

I would like the following assumption to be confirmed. The time complexity following nested for loops is identical:

```
List<Integer> smallList = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> bigList = IntStream.range(1, 1_000_000).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

for (int i : smallList) {
    for (int j : bigList) {
        doSomething(i, j);
    }
}

for (int j : bigList) {
    for (int i : smallList) {
        doSomething(i, j);
    }
}
```

My assumption is that the time complexity is identical because 5 x 1_000_000 calls of doSomething is the same as 1_000_000 x 5 calls of doSomething. Is this right? If yes, is that also true if streams are involved?

```
smallList.stream().forEach(i -> bigList.stream().forEach(j -> doSomething(i,j)));
bigList.stream().forEach(j -> smallList.stream().forEach(i -> doSomething(i,j)));
```

Is the time complexity of both above statements identical?

Comment: What makes you think they might *not* be the same?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm learning to use the streams API. But sometimes I'm lacking also some basic java knowledge. I'am reading about "Lazy evaluation" of streams and wanted to make sure that i get everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to time complexity, yes - these operations operate identically in terms of "doSomethings" executed. 5 times 1 million is naturally equal to 1 million times 5.

The problem lies in the details - I would certainly not guarantee that these operations perform identically in the real-world, because you would run into real-world restrictions like memory usage, # of cores, caching/memory alignment issues, etc. Of course, if these issues *don't* heavily impact your performance in some unexpected way, then you would expect to see both operations take an approximately equivalent time to execute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my question should be: Does "Lazy evaluation" of streams affect the time complexity in any way?

Comment: @wannaBeDev Not really, if you're going to be iterating over every element anyways. Lazy evaluation is most helpful when you can get away with not processing every element of the traversing stream.

Comment: @wannaBeDev The best benefit you'd get out of using the Streams API for operations like this is the ability to define parallel streams. Unfortunately, that's not such a great option for a beginner, since parallel streams add additional challenges to ensuring data consistency.